# Unknown AVD Error in Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I'm using the latest version of Android Studio, is my first time, also I'm install the SDK tools.

But when I want to preview my app in the virtual device I got a Unknown error, I don't know why, I was searching in but I cant find the error (I reinstall the Android Studio and stopped the AVD) but still not working.

I'm also have installed Android Studio in my Mac, and works great, I can preview my app and everything, I did the same thing in both computer, I don't know why in my PC doesn't work.

Please, any ideas will be grateful.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Go to **Tools > Android > *Uncheck* Enable ADB Integration**

then,

**Tools > Android > *Check* Enable ADB Integration**